# How to get specific information of image using Firebase-CloudVision(ML)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, image-recognition, firebase-mlkit

I am using Firebase cloudVision (ML) API to read image.
I am able to the get the information of an image back  but it is not specific.

Example: when I take and upload a picture of MacBook it is giving the output as "notebook,Loptop,electronic device..etc".

But I want to get its brand name like Apple MacBook ,
I have seen few apps doing this .
I could not find any information regarding this, so here I am posting.
Please suggest or guide if anyone come across this

My Code:

```
    func pickedImage(image: UIImage) {
    imageView.image = image
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    guard let image = imageView.image else { return }
    // let onCloudLabeler = 
        Vision.vision().cloudImageLabeler(options: options)

    let onCloudLabeler = Vision.vision().cloudImageLabeler()


    // Define the metadata for the image.
    let imageMetadata = VisionImageMetadata()


    imageMetadata.orientation = .topLeft

    // Initialize a VisionImage object with the given UIImage.
    let visionImage = VisionImage(image: image)
    visionImage.metadata = imageMetadata

    onCloudLabeler.process(visionImage) { labels, error in
        guard error == nil, let labels = labels, !labels.isEmpty 
   else {
            // [START_EXCLUDE]
            let errorString = error?.localizedDescription ?? "No results returned."
            print("Label detection failed with error: \(errorString)")
            //self.showResults()
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
            return
        }

        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        var results = [String]()
        let resultsText = labels.map { label -> String in
            results.append(label.text)
            return "Label: \(label.text), " +
                "Confidence: \(label.confidence ?? 0), " +
            "EntityID: \(label.entityID ?? "")"
            }.joined(separator: "\n")
        //self.showResults()
        // [END_EXCLUDE]
        print(results.count)
        print(resultsText)

        self.labelTxt.text = results.joined(separator: ",")
        results.removeAll()

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've seen other apps doing something that your app doesn't do, those other apps are likely using a different ML model than the one you're using.

If you want to accomplish the same using ML Kit for Firebase, you can [use a custom model](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/use-custom-models) that you either trained yourself or got from another source.

Answer (score 0):

As Puf said, the apps you saw are probably using their own custom ML model. ML Kit now supports creating custom image classification models from your own training data. Check out the AutoML Vision Edge functionality here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/automl-vision-edge